# Importing images from another site to bigcommerce store

Tags: bigcommerce

is it possible to import the images folder from the other site to our bigcommerece store like we have a site www.anothersite.com/images This images folder have all the images and we need to import all the images includes in this images folder to our bigcommerce store and it is possible or not

any help appreciated

Comment: I'm confused. Why not just upload all the images via webdav?

Comment: Sit it is due to Client requirements

Comment: What do you mean? You can't use webdav due to client requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Bigcommerce has a guide which shows exactly how to do this, a simple search of their KB would have saved you time.

https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1427/